# How is data queried from a company's in-house database server using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query

I've worked with SQL before but I'm still a novice when it comes to databases and their architecture. Let's say a company has a database server present in its building and hooked to the different computers in an office and we want to fetch some data from that server. How would the SQL commands differ from the more 'standard' syntax? How do you query the data from that server?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no inhouse vs standard.  This question is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for SQL commands is not any different in large environments. For business applications, the user will typically interact with a client - often a desktop or web application. Depending on what language the client is written in, the code will use different types of function calls to connect to the SQL server, run queries, and retrieve data. For example, in a .NET desktop application I would use the SqlClient library. Regardless of what programming language or library is used, the server will see pretty much the same thing - a standard query being executed. The queries are typically pre-programed into the client by the developer.

In a development environment, one usually uses a tool such as SQL Server Management Studio (if using Microsoft SQL Server) to execute arbitrary queries. Many other programs can also interact with SQL Server, such as Excel.